# Unable to set Null to any dateType field to Salesforce using Force.com

Tags: rest-api, force.com, force

I have tried the below code. This works when I assign some valid date to the field (of Date Type), but unable to set null to it :

```
var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password);

ForceClient client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

var a= new Account{Id="drwerew32423424"}

var success = await client.UpdateAsync("Account", a.Id, new  Account { SomeDateField= null });
```

Even using Anonymous type, gives Compile time error, as Fields cannot be assigned to null in Anonymous type object:

```
 var success = await client.UpdateAsync("Account", a.Id, new { SomeDateField= null });
```

Comment: Hi. Did you get a solution for this?